# How can I solve "windows cannot find '-n'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again" on xampp?

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I want to using 2 xampp in my windows

I had install xampp 7.0.26 in my windows. I install it in C:\xampp. And it works

I want to instal xampp 7.1.13 too. I install it in C:\xampp-7.1.13

On the last process of install, there exist error like this :

```
windows cannot find '-n'. Make sure you've typed the name correctly, then try again
```

Apparently not allowed to custom folders (C:\xampp-7.1.13)

How can I solve this error?

**Solve**

I custom the folder to be `C:\xampp-7.0` and `C:\xampp-7.1`, it works

So if the folder custom like this : `C:\xampp-7.0` and `C:\xampp-7.1`, it works

But if the folder custom like this : `C:\xampp-7.0.26` and `C:\xampp-7.1.13`, it does not work

Comment: I think this will guide you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343698/error-installing-xampp-windows-cannot-find-n)

Comment: @Chathuranga Kalana, I had read the link. But I don't find a solution

Comment: did you try install xampp on location C:\xampp instead of C:\xampp-7.1.13?

Comment: @Chathuranga Kalana, I had find a solution. See my update question

Comment: Next time you should probably post your solution as an answer, but good job on sharing it anyway :)