# Php.exe installation failed during Xampp installation

Tags: php, installation, xampp, redistributable

While installing xampp, I was unable to download php.exe:

> Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly Installation failed (php.exe). Perhaps you have to install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 redistributable package.

Here is an image of the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jyywk.png).

I saw a post with the similar error - [Error installing XAMPP: Windows cannot find -n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39343698/error-installing-xampp-windows-cannot-find-n)

However, I've tried all the solutions there:

```
- Installing xampp in the root of C drive
- Using the default folder provided (C:\xampp)
- Ensuring I have all the 2008 redistributable packages
- Change registry settings
```

But I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I got the above message while installing Xampp 7.1.12

First, open the Xampp control panel & check whether Apache service & Mysql service have been installed. Click on the button on the left side of their names. A green tick on the button before their names means they have been installed.

Then I downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package as adviced in the error message from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=29

My OS is of 32 bits. So, visit the link & check whether it matches the specifications of your OS.

I created a new foler in D: drive for Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package & installed it. After that i executed the Batch file named 'setup_xampp' located in the Xampp root folder.

Now both the Apache & Mysql services are running smoothly in Xampp control panel.

That's all !